# JGraphX - auto organise of cells and bidirectional edges

Tags: java, graph, visualization

I am using JGraphX java library to visualise a graph model and overall it seems quite good.  However, I am encountering 2 small problems.

1) Is there any possible way of having the nodes spread out in an automatic way and not defining explicity the location of where they are to be placed?

2) In the case where I have 2 edges (one from A to B, and one from B to A), is there any possible way where the user can select on of them only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok I think i managed to find a solution to my question. I discovered the `mxParallelEdgeLayout` which makes both the edges visible. I am still looking for a good layout to display my graphs but there seems a number of these which might be enough to be used. A combination of the `mxHierarchicalLayout` and the `mxParallelEdgeLayout` seems to suite my purpose.

**Example:**

```
final mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(trafficGraphVisual);
pnlGraphVisual.add(graphComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
new mxHierarchicalLayout(trafficGraphVisual).execute(trafficGraphVisual.getDefaultParent());
new mxParallelEdgeLayout(trafficGraphVisual).execute(trafficGraphVisual.getDefaultParent());
```

Comment: can you provide some example code on how you apply a layout to a graph? thx